# What is the meaning of 両岸 in this context?

Tags: words, nouns

I was reading a news article but I am not sure what 両岸 means in this context.

> 中台の間では経済や人的(てき)交流が進んでいるとしたうえで、**両岸**の関係は過去６６年間で最も平和的な状態にある.

Dictionary search result is as follows:

> りょうがん
>   両岸
>
> 1. both banks (of a river)
>
> After the heavy rains, the river overflowed its banks.
>   大雨が続いて川の水が両岸からあふれ出た。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[両岸]{りょうがん} refers to the two countries of China and Taiwan. It comes from the fact that they are on both sides (両岸) of the Taiwan Strait. So basically the same meaning as 中台.

For example, the Economic Cooperation Framework Agreement between mainland China and Taiwan is **両岸**経済協力枠組協議 in Japanese.

So,

> 両岸の関係は過去６６年間で最も平和的な状態にある.
>   China/Taiwan relations are the most peaceful they have been in the past 66 years.

Comment: 両岸 is actually a Chinese word. It's written as 两岸 in the mainland and 兩岸 in Taiwan. https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%B5%B7%E5%B3%BD%E5%85%A9%E5%B2%B8%E9%97%9C%E4%BF%82 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E6%B5%B7%E5%B3%BD%E5%85%A9%E5%B2%B8%E9%97%9C%E4%BF%82